# git rebase over current branch fails

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I have a project which I'm managing using git.

I expect each commit to apply cleanly over previous history, since the commit patch is generated by git itself.

If I have

```
------tagA--commit_A1--commit_A2--commit_A3
    \
     \[branch A]
      \
       \-commit_A'1--commit_A'2--commit_A'3--commit_A'4
```

I am on branch *A*, which stemmed from *tagA*. This is confirmed by

```
git merge-base A tagA
```

which returns *tagA*'s commit sha. I tried to issue

```
git rebase tagA
```

rebase behavior should be:

- rewind back to tagA
- apply all commits from tagA to the tip of branchA, i.e. apply commit_A'1, commit_A'2, commit_A'3, commit_A'4

The procedure should get me back to the tip of branch_A without any changes.

On the contrary, I get a conflict at one of the commits.

### Example

```
# git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git GIT_linux
# cd GIT_linux
# git remote add linux-at91 https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91.git
# git fetch linux-at91
# git checkout -b linux-3.10-at91 linux-at91/linux-3.10-at91
# git rebase v3.10
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: dmaengine: at_hdmac/trivial: correct typo in comment
Applying: dmaengine: at_hdmac: extend hardware handshaking interface identification
Applying: dmaengine: at_hdmac/trivial: rearrange CFG register bits assignment
Applying: DMA: AT91: Get transfer width
Applying: DMA: AT91: Get residual bytes in dma buffer
Applying: dma: use platform_{get,set}_drvdata()
Applying: dma: mxs-dma: Staticize mxs_dma_xlate
Applying: dma: at_hdmac: remove unnecessary platform_set_drvdata()
Applying: dma: timb_dma: remove unnecessary platform_set_drvdata()
Applying: dw_dmac: remove inline marking of EXPORT_SYMBOL functions
Applying: dma: tegra20-apbdma: err message correction
Applying: dma: tegra: avoid channel lock up after free
Applying: dmaengine: sirf: set dma residue based on the current dma transfer position
Applying: dma: of: Remove restriction that #dma-cells can't be 0
Applying: dma: of: Remove check on always true condition
Applying: dma: of: Remove restriction that #dma-cells can't be 0
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   drivers/dma/of-dma.c
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging drivers/dma/of-dma.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in drivers/dma/of-dma.c
Failed to merge in the changes.
```

Is there a reason for this to happen? Is my repository corrupted somehow?

### Rebase doesn't work, merge does...

I tried the other way around, and I could do this

```
git checkout -b my3.10.84 v3.10.84
git merge linux-at91/linux-3.10-at91
```

This resulted in just a couple conflicting files, which I fixed and committed.

Comment: "Is there a reason...?" Yes. In the commits between the original merge base of `linux-at91/linux-3.10-at91` and the tag `v3.10`, there were changes to the file `drivers/dma/of-dma.c` that conflict with the changes made to the same file in the `"dma: of: Remove restriction that #dma-cells can't be 0"` commit that `git rebase` is currently trying to process. Use `git log -p <original merge base>..v3.10` to investigate...

Comment: Maybe the commit resulted into conflict resolution in the first place, but shouldn't the corrected (i.e. non-conflicting) commit eventually have been recorded as the final patch?

Comment: @twalberg the thing is, `git merge-base linux-at91/linux-3.10-at91 v3.10` returns `v3.10` commit-id.

Comment: Commits themselves don't generally result in conflicts. You usually only see conflicts when you are either merging or rebasing. Merging conflicts occur because both (or more) branches modified the same section of code in different ways. Rebasing conflicts occur because the pre-image of a code-section before relocating a commit is different than it was when the commit was made originally, which causes the diff/patch cycle to fail.

Comment: I tried your above scenario. It appears that the issue is probably due to the fact that the set of commits you are trying to rebase contains merges. Running `git rebase -p v3.10` succeeds. My guess is that the conflict you got was one that was resolved in one of the merges, but since `git rebase` by default doesn't try to preserve merges, you ran into the same conflict (and probably would have seen others, as well, if you resolved that one)...

Comment: @twalberg it seems you are right, merges are the issue here. Would you mind adding your comment as an answer so that I can close the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failure seems to indicate that the range of commits you are trying to rebase contains merges. I tested your above sequence, but with the exception of adding the `-p` option to `git rebase` (to preserve merge commits instead of skipping over them):

```
# git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git GIT_linux
# cd GIT_linux
# git remote add linux-at91 https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91.git
# git fetch linux-at91
# git checkout -b linux-3.10-at91 linux-at91/linux-3.10-at91
# git rebase -p v3.10
```

That seems to have avoided the conflict. I think what was happening is that attempting to rebase without including the merges from the source branch failed to include any merge conflicts that were resolved by those merges, and so you would have had to re-resolve each conflict that had been resolved in any of the merges from the source branch. Including the merges in the rebase allowed `git` to resolve those conflicts in the same way they had been resolved originally.